# What are the options that I have in order to give up on the captcha

Tags: c#, .net, captcha

I want to remove the captcha from my websites at all.
Is there any way that i can make an anti-robot mechanism without captcha.

My server side is C# .NET 4.0 MVC3

Thanks

**Edit**

I want to Server side mechanism, without any of the client side involvement.
My clients are very old people and I want to make it easy on them.
BTW, I remove the capcha from my website for 10 days, I got 12% more signups.
I have tried captcha as a question and I get the same bad results.

Comment: Use the Stack Overflow API to grab a random question from the tags of your choosing, and ask the user to provide an answer!

Comment: I don't have a good reference, but I've seen people relying on the fact that most bots don't consider css or js. Sometimes bots will put data into (css-)hidden input fields, or fail to execute js that would put the expected value there.

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is a question that takes intelligence to answer --- How many  do you see? What is eight plus two? What year is it? -- anything that can't be answered by automation.

Comment: Well, I dont'think you can validate a live person with no client side interaction. You'll, at the very least, need the user to input something so you can challenge it.

Answer (score 0):

Some websites nowadays use Simple Mathematics questions instead of captchas you can go for that too

or

you can also go with simple common sense questions like how many legs a dog has

or

Some sites like google also do SMS based verifications at times you can evaluate this method too